# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() issue

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver

I keep getting the error in the header and I don't know what to do..(this is a water reminder app.) There are a lot of ridiculous topics in the forums. and nobody answered properly. I use this to run when the device restarts. I have examined many issues, but no one answered properly.

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

This is my BootReceiver class

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeProtectedBroadcastReceiver")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(service);
            Log.d("tag_boot","foreground service start");
        } else {
            context.startService(service);
            Log.d("tag_boot","service start");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my BootService class

```
public class BootService extends Service {
    private String MAIN_DATA = "com.xxxx.xxxx.MAIN";
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedpreflistener;

    public BootService() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MAIN_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        waterreceiver();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    public void waterreceiver( int su_aralik) {
        Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        int today_month_day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int today_month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int today_year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        thatDay.setTime(new Date(0)); /* reset */

        thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, today_month_day);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH, today_month); // 0-11 so 1 less
        thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, today_year);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 23 && calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 7) {
            thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1);
        } else {
            thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, today_month_day + 1);
        }

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WaterAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 7, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Objects.requireNonNull(alarmManager).setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, thatDay.getTimeInMillis(), waterlist[water_pos], pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".WaterAlarm" />
        <receiver android:name=".DietAlarm" />
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
       </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".BootService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Your service needs to call [`startForeground(int, Notification)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) within 5 seconds of being started to post notification. There are a lot of questions and answers on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

`startForegroundService` itself handles versioning no need to handle from ourselves.

**Start service:**

```
   Intent service = new Intent(context, BootService.class);
   ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, service)
```

**Stop service:**

```
stopService(new Intent(this, BootService.class));
```

Comment: when will i stop the service?

Comment: when you need to stop service ?

Comment: after completed your operation

Comment: never! needs to work constantly. different from that, I have another BroadcastRecevier class. I use this only when the phone is rebooted

Comment: ok then don't stop it and after reboot, you have to  start service again.

Comment: I added Manifest.xml

Comment: please check with the only `startForegroundService` and what result will you get?

Comment: I need to send the update again. this is a long time ago i have to solve the problem. your answer is not correct

Comment: then store it with preferences and then pass it into service next time